# Should I use use express or switch to javascript and html?

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, express

I have been building this web application that takes user input and after doing so it modifies files on the server side. The core logic of this is build in node.js and works through command line, but most of the site is build using just javascript and HTML.

I've read that using express is easier in conjunction with node to modify server-side files. Is this enough reason to switch or should I revamp my code in regular javascript?

PD: I'm new to this and this is my first web application

Comment: Please read [ask] and [what's on-topic](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and [what's not](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask).

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. Unfortunately, this sort of request for opinion is not the kind of question that the site is designed to answer. If you have specific problems getting your code to work, bring those here. You can [read more about how Stackoverflow works here.](http://stackoverflow.com/tour)

Comment: This sounds like 'Should I use Express or not'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Express is JavaScript. It is a library; a codebase from which you can do more and write less. I recommend it, especially if it is your first web app.

It is very important, as a general rule, that you don't only learn express. Just because you can use express and nothing else doesn't mean that you should. Challenge yourself to learn the inner workings of how the framework does things, and how web apps, as well as regular apps, work.

Having this knowledge will make everything easier in the long run, but that isn't to say that you should reinvent the wheel.

Overall, use Express, but make sure you know how you could do it on your own.